# how to run rspec with multiple tags

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is the sample rspec in ruby

```
require "rspec"
describe "Testing" do
    it "test1",:status => "low" do
        puts "test1"
        expect(true).to eq true
    end
    it "test2",:status => "high" do
        puts "test2"
        expect(true).to eq true
    end
    it "test3",:status => "low" do
        puts "test3"
        expect(true).to eq true
    end
    it "test4",:status => "medium" do
        puts "test4"
        expect(true).to eq true
    end
end
```

This is the command to run the high status test

```
rspec file_name --tag @status:"high"
```

Now i want to run high and medium status cases. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Filtering by tag uses a hash internally, which means that you can't
>   specify multiple filters for the same key. For instance, if you try to
>   exclude `:name => 'foo'` and `:name => 'bar'`, you will only end up
>   excluding `:name => 'bar'`.

[Read here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/command-line/tag-option).

You have to rename your tags to run multiple examples like this

```
require "rspec"
describe "Testing" do
  it "test1",low: true do
    puts "test1"
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
  it "test2", high: true do
    puts "test2"
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
  it "test3", low: true do
    puts "test3"
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
  it "test4", medium: true do
    puts "test4"
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
end
```

And run your test like this:

```
rspec <file_name> --tag high --tag medium
```

Or in your case you may just exlude one tag:

```
rspec <file_name> --tag ~status:low
```